# Oracle regular expression look behind/ahead doesn't work

Tags: xml, oracle

I have an Oracle database and I am trying process XML like

```
SELECT EXTRACT(XMLSERIALIZE(DOCUMENT XMLTYPE('<?xml version="1.0"?>
<AutoQuoteRequest xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" PolicyNum="BX78690594" TimeStamp="2019/03/11 15:18:11">
    <VehicleSymbol>JX</VehicleSymbol>
</AutoQuoteRequest>')), '//AutoQuoteRequest/VehicleSymbol') Symbol
   FROM DUAL;
```

But I get

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got -
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 73 Column: 8
```

How do I properly process XML with an Oracle SQL query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `XMLTYPE` does not need to be serialized to use `EXTRACT`. By passing the `XMLTYPE`, directly, you can provide the proper XPath to get the value you want.

```
SELECT EXTRACT (
           XMLTYPE (
               '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<AutoQuoteRequest xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" PolicyNum="BX78690594" TimeStamp="2019/03/11 15:18:11">
    <VehicleSymbol>JX</VehicleSymbol>
</AutoQuoteRequest>'),
           '//AutoQuoteRequest/VehicleSymbol/text()')    Symbol
  FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an `XMLTABLE`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   XMLTABLE(
         '//AutoQuoteRequest'
         PASSING XMLTYPE('<?xml version="1.0"?>
<AutoQuoteRequest xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" PolicyNum="BX78690594" TimeStamp="2019/03/11 15:18:11">
    <VehicleSymbol>JX</VehicleSymbol>
</AutoQuoteRequest>'
         )
         COLUMNS
           symbol CHAR(2) PATH './VehicleSymbol'
       );
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> | SYMBOL |
> | :----- |
> | JX     |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ccfe134b5c587eecba83933b44ea269c)*